Why do we need async and io_context?
I'm studying multithreading, and I came across that it is preferable to use async() with io_context. But I don’t quite understand why they are needed. I re-read several documentations and watched many lectures on this topic, but I still couldn’t figure out what the difference, for example, in this code:
boost::asio::io_context io;

io.post([](){ 
   do_some_work() 
});

std::thread thread([&io]() {
 io.run();
});

from this:
std::thread thread([&io]() {
 do_some_work();
});

I also saw many examples of using io_context with async in client-server interaction with so-called handlers. But I just don’t understand their meaning. Why are they needed if you can just write methods in a row:
socket();
connect();
read();
handle();

Why use a complex async construction with io_context, if you can write everything structurally (as I did above) using future/promise and it will be readable and understandable?

Threads are a pretty heavy-weight thing to create, while the individual operations scheduled on that thread are cheap in comparison to the thread creation overhead. Also, async operations for more than one strand of execution may complete out of order and with batched results. There's also things you can't do with the synchronous API, such as setting up receive buffers so far ahead of time that the network card can actually use them almost directly as a target, without having to wake your process.

With synchronous socket calls you can only handle one connection per thread, in general it takes much longer to send and receive data over the network than it takes to process the data, this leads to the thread spending most of its time being idle waiting for operations to complete. In a server handling lots of connections, creating a new thread for every connection could be inefficient, threads are generally relatively expensive to create and maintain.
Asynchronous code helps solve this problem, a thread can do the processing for a connection then asynchronously send the results, whilst it's waiting for the send to complete the thread can go and handle a different connection. This means that you can handle many connections at once with just a small pool of threads.
io_context is the asio implementation of this thread pool. In your trivial example, yes there is no benefit to using it but a more realistic example would be:
boost::asio::io_context io;
void do_some_work(){
  // Do some asynchronous operation
  // Run the callback for it
  io.post(async_complete());
}
for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++)
{
  io.post([](){ 
     do_some_work() 
  });
}

std::thread thread([&io]() {
 io.run();
});


io_context the asio implementation of a thread pool ?! I'm pretty sure that boost::asio::thread_pool is the thread pool implementation. It pretty much says so in the name. In fact, the whole point of io.run() is that the io_context needs a thread of execution to actually do something; it doesn't have its own.

@MSalters ok, more precisely its the work queue which can then be used by a thread pool to execute the tasks, I was more trying to explain the basic concepts of asynchronous code rather than the technical details of asio

Okay, but can't we write the same thing simply by creating a thread and looping in it? Like this:
std::thread thread(&io {
for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++)
{
do_some_work()
}
async_complete()
});

Or is the main purpose of using io_context is executing operations in queue?

it's for executing operations in a queue, your loop would do all the work then call the callback, the asio version would do each piece of work (potentially all simulataneously) then call the callback for each bit of work, all on a single thread

To answer the last part of the question: why not future/promise ? That's because it wouldn't work. You'd need std::async instead of std::promise to actually do something. And that has no direct control over the threads of execution. std::launch::async requires new threads, or at least threads that look new (thread-locals cleared)
The more logical solution to your pattern
socket();
connect();
while(...) {
   read();
   handle();
}

would be
co_await socket();
co_await connect();
while(...) {
    co_yield read();
}

(Using C++20 coroutines - the co_yield allows the caller to handle each return value)
